# appsync using elasticsearch as datasource: Elasticsearch responded with an error: Forbidden

Tags: elasticsearch, aws-appsync

I'm trying to use ElasticSearch as a datasource in AppSync, but I got this:

Elasticsearch responded with an error: Forbidden

I'm using the role created by AppSync. I even tried to add Full access on ES in the same role with no success.

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have been struggling with the same problem for a few days.
In my case, the problem was that the auto-generated IAM role was given permissions for ES endpoint and it was solved by changing "Resource" reference to the whole ES domain. For example:

*Before:*

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/search-foo-bar-search-someid123.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com"
]
```

*After:*

```
"Resource": [
    "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/foo-bar-search/*"
]
```

Comment: I see the `""arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/search-foo-bar-search-..."` is replaced with `"arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/foo-bar-search/*"`. Does it correctly match with the `/`? This would be surprising.

Comment: @MichalGajda Sorry, didn't get your question. If you are asking whether `"arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/foo-bar-search/"` will work without `*` then no, it won't refer to any resources. But there are other working versions like `"arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/foo-bar-search"` and `"arn:aws:es:us-east-1:11111:domain/*"`